# ffmpeg determine frame number for fade filter

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am looking for an easy way to set the time points for the fade filter. Particularly for the fade-out at the end. At best would be a time based format. I understand the fade filter works based on frames. But is there a way to change that to time stamp? Particularly in the end I have a hard time getting the number of the last frame. Some means to tell the fade filter to start the fade 0.5sec before the end would be awesome. Maybe something like:

```
-filter:v 'fade=out:-0.5:0.3'
```

Read : 'start fade out 0.5sec before end and have fade take 0.3sec. I.e. have 0.2sec of black at the end.

I would also be OK if this would be in frame number counts.

My grief right now is that the frame count i.e. reported by ffprobe seems to be somewhat half of what it really is. A fade filter applied on the count provided by ffprobe turn my video to black about half-way through the clip. I'm not sure what I'm missing there.

Again my primary question is: How to determine the correct frame number for the fade out filter?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fade filter does take time input: e.g. `-vf fade=out:st=23:d=2`. This starts a 2-second fade-out at `t=23` seconds